# return length of file name in python (shell)

Tags: python, listdir

I wanted to write a Python Script that lists all files in the current working directory, if the **length** of a file's name is between 3 - 6 characters long. Also, it should only list files with the extension `.py`

I was not able to find any specific function that would return the legnth of a files name, only the size of its contet.

Here is what my code looks like so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os

for file in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    if file.endswith(".py"):
        print(file)
```

Can anyone tell me what the solution could look like? Do I use a RegEx in the `os.getcwd(RegEx)` function?

**edit:**

I am sorry for posting this trivial question. I found the solution and it looks as followed:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os

for file in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    if file.endswith(".py"):
        if ((len(os.path.splitext(file)[0])) > 2 and (len(os.path.splitext(file)[0])) < 7):
            print(file)
```

This works for my intended purpose. Thanks for the answers, they made me realize that using len(filename) was an option and therefore my question was not very smart.

Comment: Is there a reason that `len()` wouldn't work here along with an `if` statement?

Comment: What does this have to do with shell?

Comment: You don't need a specific function, as a file name is just  a string. Use `len` as you would with any other string.

Comment: @chepner yes, you are right. I was just a bit confused because I needed the length of the files name without the extension itself

Answer (score 2):

Maybe rewording `file` to `filename` might make things clearer...

```
import os

for filename in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    if filename.endswith(".py"):
        print(filename, len(filename))
```

Now since you know how `if` statements work, you can probably do something with `len(filename)`? :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
import os

for file in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    if file.endswith(".py") and 3 <= len(file[:file.find(".")]) <= 6:
        print(file)
```

This will print only files that have between 3 and 6 chars in the filename without the file extension.

Answer (score 1):

your variable `file` is a string
so, you can use a function for retrive a lenght of a string

```
for file in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
     if file.endswith(".py"):
         print(file, len(file))
```